# Queue manager. Multithreading management implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, server

I want to write small server that has one thread that pushes some jobs into queue and several threads that pull the jobs and process it somehow.

I wrote (of course no, I found an example) of blocking queue. Then I wrote `cFakeWorker` that is server prototype. In general it works ok, but I'm not sure that the way I implemented termination is very good. And, so far, I will appreciate for ideas how should be done.

Currently I have `m_bForceStop` member of `cBlockingQueue` class. `pull()` function checks its state with `condition_variable` and throws exception in case of termination.

`cFakeWorker` catches this exception while waits for the new jos.

The moment I call `cBlockingQueue::stop_waiting()` is `cFakeWorker::Terminate()`. This implementation works, but I have bad feeling that it might be done better. So I will appreciate for the review.

**UPDATE! Uploading all sources** 
@Phrancis, thanks for the comment. I will appreciate for comments.

main.cpp

```
void main()
{
    cFakeWorker fw;

    std::thread thFW([&fw](){fw.StartFlow();});

    while (true)
    {
        std::string s;

        std::cin >> s;
        if (s == "exit")
        {
            std::cout << __func__ << " Terminating .... " << std::endl;
            fw.Terminate();
            std::cout << __func__ << " Termination done" << std::endl;

            thFW.join();
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

cFakeWorker.h

```
#ifndef CFAKEWORKER_H
#define CFAKEWORKER_H

#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

#include "cBlockingQueue.h"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct taskData
{
    std::string str;
    std::chrono::milliseconds sleep_period;
};


class cFakeWorker
{
public:
    cFakeWorker();
    virtual ~cFakeWorker();

    void StartFlow();
    void Terminate();
private:

    cBlockingQueue<taskData> m_queue;
    int m_NCores;
    int m_NPullThreads;

    std::vector<std::thread> m_vecPullThreads;
    std::thread m_PushThread;

    std::mutex m_mtxIO;
    std::mutex m_mtxTerminate;
    std::condition_variable m_cvTerminate;
    bool m_bForceTermination;

    void PushJob();
    void PullJob();
};

#endif /* CFAKEWORKER_H */
```

cFakeWorker.cpp

```
#include "cFakeWorker.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand()
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sched.h>

cFakeWorker::cFakeWorker()
{
    m_NCores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    m_NPullThreads = (m_NCores > 1) ? m_NCores - 1 : 1;
}

void cFakeWorker::StartFlow()
{
    m_bForceTermination = false;

    m_PushThread = std::thread([this](){this->PushJob();});

    for (int i = 0; i < m_NPullThreads; i++)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lckIO(m_mtxIO);
            std::cout << "Starting pull thread #" << i << std::endl;    

            m_vecPullThreads.push_back(std::thread([this](){this->PullJob();}));
        }
    }
}

void cFakeWorker::PushJob()
{
    std::condition_variable cv;

    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));

    while (true)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mtxTerminate);

            if(m_bForceTermination)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        std::stringstream ss;

        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);

        ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%Y %a %b %d %H:%M:%S");

        int nSleepDuration = ( std::rand() + 1) % 999;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

        taskData dat;
        dat.str = ss.str();
        dat.sleep_period = std::chrono::milliseconds(nSleepDuration);
        m_queue.push(dat);
    }
}

void cFakeWorker::PullJob()
{
    while (m_queue.is_waiting())
    {
        try
        {
            taskData dat;

            try
            {
                dat = m_queue.pull();
            }
            catch (const cTerminationException & ex)
            {
                std::cout << __func__ << ": " << "cBlockingQueue::pull() was terminated" << std::endl;
                return;
            }


            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lckIO(m_mtxIO);
                std::cout << " Start doing "
                            << "------ >>> " 
                            << "CPU: " << sched_getcpu()
                            << " ["  << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] --" 
                            << " msg : " << dat.str
                            << " sleep: " << dat.sleep_period.count()
                            << std::endl;


            }

            // fake load
            for(int i = 1; i < 50000; i++)
            {
                char * p = new char [i];

                for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                {
                    p[j] = 2;
                }

                delete [] p;
            }

            std::cout << " Stop doing "
                            << "------ >>> " 
                            << "CPU: " << sched_getcpu()
                            << std::endl;

        }
        catch (const std::exception & ex)
        {
            std::cout << __func__ << ": " << "something has happened. Keep pulling" << std::endl;
        }

    }
}

void cFakeWorker::Terminate()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mtxTerminate);
        m_bForceTermination = true;
    }
    m_PushThread.join();

    m_queue.stop_waiting();

    for (auto& th : m_vecPullThreads)
    {
        th.join();
    }
}

cFakeWorker::~cFakeWorker()
{
    try
    {
        Terminate();
    }
    catch (const std::exception & ex)
    {}
}
```

cBlockingQueue.h (example code I found)

> ```
> #ifndef CBLOCKINGQUEUE_H
> #define CBLOCKINGQUEUE_H
>
> #include <mutex>
> #include <deque>
> #include <condition_variable>
> #include <thread>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <chrono>
> using namespace std::chrono_literals;
>
> class cTerminationException : public std::exception
> {
> };
>
>
> template <typename T>
> class cBlockingQueue
> {
> public:
>
>   cBlockingQueue()
>   {
>       m_bForceStop = false;
>   }
>
>   void push(const T & param)
>   {
>       {
>           std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
>           m_deque.push_front(param);
>       }
>
>       m_cv.notify_all();
>   }
>
>   T pull()
>   {
>       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mut);
>       m_cv.wait(lock, [=](){return !this->m_deque.empty() || m_bForceStop;});
>
>       if (m_bForceStop)
>       {
>           std::cout << __func__ << " Throwing cTerminationException" << std::endl;
>           throw cTerminationException();
>       }
>
>       T ret(std::move(m_deque.back()));
>       m_deque.pop_back();
>
>       return ret;
>   }
>
>   void stop_waiting()
>   {
>       m_bForceStop = true;
>       m_cv.notify_all();
>   }
>
>   bool is_waiting()
>   {
>       return !m_bForceStop;
>   }
>
> private:
>   std::mutex m_mut;
>   std::deque<T> m_deque;
>   std::condition_variable m_cv;
>
>   bool m_bForceStop;
>
> };
>
>
> #endif /* CBLOCKINGQUEUE_H */
> ```

Comment: `I found an example` so did you write it yourself or not?

Comment: Everything except cBlockingQueue. The queue I've copied from example and added termination for the `push()` method

Answer (score 2):

## `main.cpp`

```
void main()
```

This is not valid C++. `main()` must return `int`.

```
while (true)
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    // ...
```

This works... sorta... but it's not exactly the most efficient way to go about it. The problem is that on each loop, the string `s` is destroyed and then recreated, and then filled with data. If you move the string *outside* of the loop, then its memory is retained on each loop iteration.

But the more important issue is that you're not checking to see if `std::cin` is in a fail state. If the input hits `EOF` before getting "exit", or if there's any kind of input failure, your program will just spin forever. What you want to do is check that the input succeeded.

So what you have now is something like this:

```
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s)
{
    // ...
```

This could also be written:

```
for (std::string s; std::cin >> s; )
{
    // ...
```

This is more efficient, and - more importantly - if there's any kind of input error, your program will exit.

However, now that you're exiting both on "exit" and on input error, you will need to move your termination logic outside of the loop:

```
for (std::string s; std::cin >> s; )
{
    if (s == "exit")
        break;
}

// Do termination here.
```

Next is:

```
std::cout << __func__ << " Terminating .... " << std::endl;
```

Don't use `std::endl`. All you need is:

```
std::cout << __func__ << " Terminating .... \n";
```

## `cFakeWorker.h`

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

Using directives normally shouldn't be in headers. And you don't even use it in the header.

```
class cFakeWorker
```

Prefixing identifiers with type information is bad practice in C++. Prefixing private members with `m_` is okay-ish, but prefixing classes with `c` or `C` is totally unnecessary. That also goes for all the `N`, `vec`, and so on, but even more so, because it makes it more difficult if you ever want to change types.

```
virtual ~cFakeWorker();
```

Unless you intend for a type to be inheritable, there's no need to make the destructor virtual. `cFakeWorker` doesn't seem like a type built for extending - it has no other virtual functions, for example.

```
int m_NCores;
int m_NPullThreads;
```

Are these two variables really necessary? The only time you use `m_NCores` is to determine `m_NPullThreads`... and the only time you use `m_NPullThreads` is when you create the pull threads (after that, `m_NPullThreads` is equal to `m_vecPullThreads.size()`). The only thing the constructor does is set these variables, so without them, you don't need the constructor either.

```
std::mutex m_mtxTerminate;
std::condition_variable m_cvTerminate;
bool m_bForceTermination;
```

There seems an awful lot of complexity here that really isn't necessary. For starters, it doesn't seem like you actually use `m_cvTerminate`. And it looks like the only purpose of `m_mtxTerminate` is to guard `m_bForceTermination`, and you don't use it consistently.

It seems to me that you can accomplish everything these variables do with a single atomic `bool`. As a bonus, that might even make it lock-free.

```
std::atomic<bool> m_bForceTermination = false;
```

## `cFakeWorker.cpp`

```
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand()
```

Don't use `rand()`. It was always a terrible random number generator, and *nobody* uses it properly. (You are not using it properly either.)

C++ has a *much* better random library, and once you've had it explained to you, it's *really* easy to use. All you use `rand()` for is to generate a number between 1 and 998, so all you need is this:

```
#include <random>

auto generate_sleep_duration()
{
    static auto eng = std::default_random_engine{std::random_device{}()};
    static auto dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{1, 998};

    return dist(eng);
}
```

Even better: since you want it to be `std::chrono::milliseconds`, you can return `std::chrono::milliseconds`.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
```

Is there any need for the second include? In any case, including C headers (like `<time.h>` rather than `<ctime>`) in C++ is deprecated.

The default constructor seems unnecessary.

With `StartFlow()`, you don't take into account what should happen if `StartFlow()` is called twice in a row, or `StartFlow(); Terminate(); StartFlow();`. That could be intentional; you may intend for doing those things to be undefined behaviour. I'm just warning you.

### `cFakeWorker::PushJob()`

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
```

These first two lines should probably be removed. You never use the condition variable, and this is the wrong place to call `srand()`. *If* you were going to use `rand()`, `srand()` should be called only once globally. With this design, it will be called every time you start a new push thread.

```
while (true)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_mtxTerminate);

        if(m_bForceTermination)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

If you change `m_bForceTermination` to be an `atomic<bool>`, all of the above becomes:

```
while (!m_bForceTermination)
{
```

Next:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
```

First, `auto` is your friend:

```
auto tp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

But the real problem here is that you're mixing clocks. This happens to work on your system, probably because `system_clock` and `high_resolution_clock` are the same. But it is not guaranteed to work generally.

Using a high resolution clock is specious in this situation anyway. All you do with it is print the time at a 1 second resolution. You don't need any more resolution than that.

### `cFakeWorker::PullJob()`

The nested `try` blocks bother me - this function could be flattened:

```
while (m_queue.is_waiting())
{
    try
    {
        auto dat = m_queue.pull();

        // rest of stuff in inner try block
    }
    catch (const cTerminationException & ex)
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << ": " << "cBlockingQueue::pull() was terminated\n";
        return;
    }
    catch (const std::exception & ex)
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << ": " << "something has happened. Keep pulling\n";
    }
}
```

I realize the fake load is just, well, "fake", but it could still be done a lot better:

```
    // fake load
    for(int i = 1; i < 50000; i++)
        auto v = std::vector<signed char>(i, 2);
```

But why not just sleep, right?

### `cFakeWorker::Terminate()`

`Terminate()` by itself isn't too bad, but the problem is that `Terminate()` is not built to be called multiple times, but you call it manually and also in the destructor. I'm actually surprised that your test program doesn't terminate (due to throwing an unhandled exception), because you join threads in the destructor that have already been shut down. Maybe I'm missing something.

To fix the issue, you need to only do cleanup if required. How you figure out how to do that is up to you. (You also need to properly cleanup. After joining all the pull threads, you don't clear the vector... but in `StartFlow()`, you begin pushing new threads without checking to see if the vector is empty. You probably want to call `m_vecPullThreads.clear()` after joining the threads.)

## `cBlockingQueue.h`

I assume since this is someone else's code, it's not part of the review, right?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thanks a lot! I agree with you, all these things must be improved. Thanks one more